# How to get a list of suggested tags from Youtube API?

Tags: tags, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When editing a Youtube video at youtube.com, if you type text into the list of tags on a video, there is an auto-complete drop-down showing predefined tags that match the text you are typing. This list of tags would be useful for developers building an application that lets users upload videos via the API because the auto-complete feature would stop typos, give suggestions, etc.

So my question is: How do I get a list of suggested tags from the Youtube API? (If that is even possible). **EDIT:** And by "suggested" I mean tags with names that start with text matching a given search term.

I could not find anything about it in the docs. Also in the entry for the v3 upload feature[1] of the API, the list of tags appears to be a list of arbitrary strings, which suggests there isn't a list of tag Ids on which to map tag entries of the new video. Also the list of Resource Types available in the API[2] doesn't contain any reference to "tags" or "keywords", which again suggests that a tag search feature isn't available in the API. But it would be great if someone know how to get this list.

[1] https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video
[2] https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Comment: Did you got any luck with that, I'm looking for same thing